# What is the difference between using {} and '' as attribute value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In most React projects I've worked in, I came to several instance of JSX where attribute enclosed value with curly bracket, `{''}`, or it does not use curly bracket `''`.

For example.

`<input name={'name'} />` and `<input name='name' />`

`<div id={'id'}>...</div>` and `<div id='id'>...</div>`

The code appears to compile just fine.

What is the main difference between using curly bracket and without curly bracket?

Comment: String values do not need the curly braces. It's completely optional for literal string values. Plugins like Prettier may add the braces for you, because it's more consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fine to use {''} and "" for string literals but on other hand, if you want to assign value dynamically then should go for {}

`<div className={classes.styles}>..</div>`

Answer (score 3):

The outer curly braces tell the JSX parser that the syntax should be interpreted as javascript. then the quotes inside are for strings.
unnecessary and a waste of extra typing,
but `` used for putting a dynamic variable inside, usually for css purpose.
example:

```js
className={`${inverted ? 'inverted' : ''}`}
```